# Apache has just stopped working in XAMPP, new version says UAC issues

Tags: php, apache, xampp

Alright, so I've run into multiple issues with XAMPP.
First it started when I would try to run Apache and would receive the "Apache shutdown unexpectedly" error, so I did some troubleshooting and figured it would be best to just uninstall and reinstall a newer version since I was behind anyway.

So I go to install the new version and receive this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/MZE1V.png

Well, my UAC is turned off..so I can't possibly be having that issue. Tried to install anyway, but my XAMPP version number is still my PREVIOUS version of XAMPP even though I made sure to uninstall and reset before installing the newer version. Upon checking the logs I received "this file has not been created, would you like to create one?".

So I'm stuck here, anybody have a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Ive had a similar problem- Installed XAMPP yesterday. Where you install your XAMPP...

->right click on the file "xampp"

->Properties

->Security

->Under 'Group or user names' click your user

->Then click on "To change permission, click Edit", and click the "Edit..."

->Click on you user again, and "Allow" yourself "Full Control"

->Click Apply

Let me know if this works